# Missing bootstrap resources in Django-Rest-Framework

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I'm using the new [django-rest-framework 2.0](http://django-rest-framework.org/topics/rest-framework-2-announcement.html) and have been following the tutorial for creating a rest based API. The API is now complete, however I am having trouble getting the bootstrap resources to load, all return with a 404 Not Found from Django.

I feel like the resources should be loaded from django-rest-framework module's static directory, And when I do a listing on 'python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/static/rest_framework' I see the css, js, and img directories I need with but I have been unable to find any place in the documentation that shows how to link the CSS from the module to my project.

What is the best course of action here? Should I download the source and copy the folder into my /static directory? Symlinking is out of the question because I need to check the project into a central repo.. Ideas?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

First up, I'm assuming that you mean the bootstrap static resources aren't loading for the browsable API?  (Although I guess it could be that you're trying to use them elsewhere in your project?)

If you're running with `DEBUG=True` they should be served automatically, but once you're running with `DEBUG=False` you need to make sure to run `manage.py collectstatic` and ensure your `STATIC_ROOT` and `STATIC_URL` settings are correct.

Django's static files documentation should help: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/

If you're still not having any luck I'd suggest you double check your Django version (1.3 and upwards is supported), and REST framework version (Anything from version 2 onwards), and make sure you step through the tutorial step-by-step, taking care particularly with the project setup.

Comment: Definitely should have read the docs a little more thoroughly before asking this question. I missed adding 'django.contrib.staticfiles' to my settings.py, and immediately saw the problem was corrected! Thanks for your help, your REST framework has been invaluable in creating our new API!

Comment: manage.py collectstatic actually copies the files, in my application I found it much easier to simply add a symbolic link to the static directory within the package installation (under dist-packages)

Comment: Also make sure you have a folder named `static` in the appropriate location, I needed to follow the instructions above as well as those [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19323513/heroku-django-oserror-no-such-file-or-directory-app-myappname-static) to fix my issues with Heroku not serving the static files

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Heroku you'll want to make sure you are using the configurations in the getting started documentation (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-django). See the section "settings.py" and "wsgi.py". I was having the same problem and this solved it.

settings.py

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

wsgi.py

```
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from dj_static import Cling
application = Cling(get_wsgi_application())
```

Answer (score -1):

CSS is not found. The fix would be to make the missing css files (404 for files seen in the browser console) available. That's it.

You can make the css files accessible in backend(need some tweaks) or in front end(comparatively easy).

This solution works perfect if you have a seperate frontend & backend(restful) setup such as Django-Django rest framework and AngularJS..

Let us say if django backend is running at 8000, and front end is running at 9000.

- frontend.example.com loads front end JS app running at 9000
- backend.example.com loads django app running at 8000

in `settings.py`

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

STATIC_URL = 'http://frontend.example.com/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

then in terminal

```
$ python manage.py collectstatic
```

Then go to dir where you have the folder `static`

```
$ cp -rf static/* /frontend-code-directory/static/
```

DONE.

What I have done basically, is copying all css of django apps to the frontend. Frontend serves this easy as frontend is already a collection of static files.