# Heroku & Django: "OSError: No such file or directory: '/app/{myappname}/static'"

Tags: python, django, git, heroku, django-staticfiles

I have a Django app on Heroku. I am having some problems with static files (they are loading in one Heroku [environment](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/multiple-environments) but not another), so I tried the debug command recommended [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets#debugging).

```
$ heroku run python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
Running `python manage.py collectstatic --noinput` attached to terminal... up, run.8771
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/app/{myappname}/static'
```

Here is my settings.py, which is the same thing Heroku recommends:

```
import os
import os.path

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

I get the error whether or not I actually have a directory "static" at the root level in my Git repo (tested it both ways).

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post your INSTALLED_APPS?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

It's looking for a folder named 'static' that's next to the settings.py, i.e. in the project folder, not at the root of the git repo.

```
git root/
git root/{app name}
git root/{app name}/settings.py
git root/{app name}/static/         <- this is what you're missing
```

Note that empty folders aren't tracked by git, so you'll have to put a blank file in there if it's empty. Alternatively, remove the `STATICFILES_DIRS` setting until you need it.

Comment: I had the same problem on a heroku site, and the only thing missing was a blank .gitignore file!

Comment: Almost nothing worked for me, except the last item "Alternatively, remove the STATICFILES_DIRS setting until you need it" which made everything work beautifully.  Heroku would not "collect static" until that line went away.

Comment: Perfect man, this was the problem I was having. I just couldn't figure out where to put the damn templates.

Comment: I like the last part of the answer. `...remove the STATICFILES_DIRS setting until you need it.` E.g. One does not really need it in the Development server.

Answer (score 17):

I just had this same problem, and here's the solution that worked for me:

I changed:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

to:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'myappfolder/static'),
)
```

Comment: This worked for me as well, although my path required moving up a directory: `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../myappfolder/static')`

Comment: none of them works for me, it is, "myappfolder " means the name of your app on heroku or just myappfolder

Answer (score 1):

@joerick's answer above is the thing. However, if you do not want to place another 'static' folder (git root/{your app}/static), you might consider changing the BASE_DIR variable that is initially supplied by django-admin makeproject:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

which is just the (git root/) directory