# DjangoRestFramework browsable api looks different locally vs when deployed on server?

Tags: django-rest-framework

When I do `python manage.py runserver` I see this:

[image: local]

After I deployed it to AWS, I accessed the URL and this is what I see:

[image: after deploying]

Why does it look so different after deploying it? And how do I get it to look like how it is on the local server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

following link may help you solving this error

[missing-static-directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25375448/django-rest-framework-missing-static-directory)

and if this does not work then you can recollect static files with...

```
python /path/to/your/project/manage.py collectstatic --noinput
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an issue with Django REST framework. You are not serving the static files. Django explains how to deploy static files [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/deployment/)