# Django - static files not found both locally and on Heroku

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, docker, heroku

I have a problem with static files using Django with Docker on Heroku.
 When I open app I get errors like this on Heroku:

```
2017-07-13T13:37:43.271635+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/rest_framework/js/default.js" host=myapp.herokuapp.com request_id=3bfd8d31-193e-48e8-bb6e-aee9f353ffee fwd="109.173.154.199" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=15ms status=404 bytes=291 protocol=https
```

and like this locally:

```
django_1   | [13/Jul/2017 13:35:01] "GET /static/rest_framework/js/default.js HTTP/1.1" 404 109
```

I tried to do it on the basis of many answers, for instance [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25375448/django-rest-framework-missing-static-directory), unfortunately nothing works. Any suggestions?

My `settings.py` based on [Heroku documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets):

```
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static'),
)
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

I added `whitenoise` to `requirements.txt`.

wsgi.py:

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from whitenoise.django import DjangoWhiteNoise

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "project.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
application = DjangoWhiteNoise(application)
```

**SOLUTION**
I couldn't run `python3 manage.py collectstatic` because of `No such file or directory static in my project tree`. Then `python3 manage.py collectstatic` solved my problem.

Comment: Did you install and set up whitenoise, as recommended in the Heroku documentation?

Comment: Yes, I did. I updated my post, too.

Comment: You used the `collectstatic` command? Are all static files copied?

Comment: When I run `python3 manage.py collectstatic`I get `No such file or directory: '/Users/myUser/Projects/DockerProject/Project/backend/project/project/static'`

Comment: I have created directory `static` manually. Everything works fine both locally and on Heroku. Thanks for your support. I will update my post.

Comment: @Wahtdbogh was this comment for me? I didn't do anything. Or did my collectstatic hint made you find the mistake?

Comment: It was a comment to you and Flimm. I just wanted to thank you for your willingness to help.