# Django Rest Framework Missing Bootstrap

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

It's nearly the same question as this:

[Missing bootstrap resources in Django-Rest-Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13258087/missing-bootstrap-resources-in-django-rest-framework)

and [Django -- Can't get static CSS files to load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7574759/django-cant-get-static-css-files-to-load)

So it seems that this may be a more common issue.  I checked my settings with the first one and I am not using runserver for the 2nd one.

My settings:
DEBUG = False

and installed apps includes:
'django.contrib.staticfiles',

I am running django 1.5 and the latest version of django-rest 2.3.8, using uwsgi + nginx on a Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.  The API themselves are being served but the bootstrap and css files are not.  When i click into the link in some API and check out the source code for: href = /static/rest_framework/css/bootstrap.min.css

I get the default django 404 url not found.

I think I just missed a step somewhere in the installation but I can't figure out where.

Comment: This kind of posts should always include the parts of template where you have descibed static files paths.

Answer (score 3):

I find a simple way to solve it.I guess you must use the uwsgi and nginx.
uwsgi can't find the rest_framework static file.
you can add the following to your nginx config file:

```
location /static/rest_framework/ {
alias /yourdjangoproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/static/rest_framework/;}
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem is most likely something like using {{ STATIC_ROOT }} not {{ STATIC_URL }} in path, just like the links you refer to say.

Answer (score 0):

Did you run collectstatic ?
If so, you don't have to alias DRF's static files.

Hope it helps.