# Django debug page layout is broken

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I just launched my Django server, and trying to access it through browser, but the layout is broken, how to fix this issue?

[image]

Comment: did you run `python manage.py collectstatic`?   related question [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13258087/missing-bootstrap-resources-in-django-rest-framework), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25375448/django-rest-framework-missing-static-directory)

Comment: Your CSS is not being served.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your settings.py and urls.py.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all for your quick response, I just fixed this issue with following method:

Environment: Apache and WSGI

1. Add following line to `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default`

> ```
> Alias /static/ /path/to/mysite.com/static/
> <Directory /path/to/mysite.com/static> 
>     Require all granted
> </Directory>
> ```

2. Add following line to `settings.py`

> ```
> STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR + '/static'
> STATIC_URL = '/static/'
> ```

3. Run `python manage.py collectstatic` and restart Apache