# Where should I import debug_toolbar.models

Tags: python, django, django-debug-toolbar

I got confused by the official doc of django-debug-toolbar, http://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.org/en/1.3.2/installation.html

According to the `Explicit setup`, I did below steps:

- pip install django-debug-toolbar
- set `static` folder as [Django debug page layout is broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32282242/django-debug-page-layout-is-broken)
- add `debug_toolbar` to INSTALLED_APPS
- `DEBUG` is True in settings.py
- `debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware` added in settings.py
- `DEBUG_TOOLBAR_PATCH_SETTINGS = False` added in settings.py
- `INTERNAL_IPS = ('127.0.0.1', 'xxx.xx.xxx',)` added in settings.py
- `if settings.DEBUG: ...` added in urls.py as official doc
- My json data is showing in Django REST framework template, so I think there is no `</body>` issue for this problem.

And the toolbar didn't show up, then I found below notes from the official doc

> The automatic setup relies on debug_toolbar.models being imported when
>   the server starts. Django doesn’t provide a better hook to execute
>   code during the start-up sequence. This works with manage.py runserver
>   because it validates models before serving requests.

I didn't import `debug_toolbar.models` in above steps, do I need to do it? and where?

Answer (score 0):

No, i don't think you need to import `debug_toolbar.models`.

- Check if `DEBUG` is set to `True`. The debug toolbar won't be visible if it is set to `False`.
- Check if `INTERNAL_IPS` is set in your settings. The Debug Toolbar is shown only if your IP is listed in the `INTERNAL_IPS` setting. 
  If browsing locally, add `INTERNAL_IPS = ('127.0.0.1',)` otherwise add your IPs to the tuple.
- Check if you have added the debug toolbar middleware class in the `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` settings. Add `'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware'` class to your settings. Include the Debug Toolbar middleware as early as possible in the list. However, it must come after any other middleware that encodes the response’s content, such as `GZipMiddleware`.
- Check if your template file is of type `text/html` and has a closing `</body>` and `</html>` tag.

Comment: thanks for your response, DEBUG is True in my settings.py

Comment: Check if you have added `INTERNAL_IPS` and middleware class to the settings

Comment: thanks, I just checked all items of `Explicit setup` in official doc, and still doesn't work

Comment: Check if your template file is of type `text/html` and has a closing `</body>` and `</html>` tag.

Comment: Ah.. where is  template file?

Comment: Check if the template which you are displaying contains an explicit closing </body> and </html> tag.

Comment: My json data is embedded in Django REST framework template, if you are talking abou this template, the answer is yes