# Django production settings for static 404

Tags: django, static

I am trying to get my project up in production on my localhost, however the static files are all returning 404 except the CDNs.

--settings.py--

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1']

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static","static_root")

STATIC_URL = "/static/"

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static", "our_static"),
    # '/var/www/static/',
)
```

Then I have some extra code in my urls.py, maybe it could be causing trouble

--urls.py--

```
]+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: `STATIC_URL` should be something like `'/static/'`. It shouldn't rely on `STATIC_ROOT` (which is the location on the server where the static files are served from).

Comment: oh I forgot to change it back to static, I tried to test it out to see if it made any difference, but both bringing up 404 errors

Comment: You haven't shown your server config (e.g. Apache or Nginx) which you are using to serve static files in production.

Comment: I am only running the server on django for now, to get things up and running.

Comment: You've misunderstood how static files work. In development, Django's runserver can serve static files. In production, your server (e.g. Apache or Nginx) is responsible for serving static files. You can't get things 'up and running' in production with Django alone.

Comment: The Django server is *not* for production use. Do not run it on your production machine.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will set up my Apache then.

Comment: As an aside, you can remove the first `+= static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)`, since you are doing the same thing below in your `if settings.DEBUG` block.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Django with Apache and WSGI, you can serve static files following [Django debug page layout is broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32282242/django-debug-page-layout-is-broken), and put all your static files under `/path/to/mysite.com/static/`

Answer (score 0):

Your `settings.DEBUG` is set to `False`. Thus static and media urls are not mapped to respective root settings. Either make `DEBUG = true` in setting files or remove if condition in *urls.py*.